# Facebook login not valid in windows phone 8

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been trying to use facebook login in my windows phone app. I am using facebook sdk for dot net.

Whenever I try to login using

```
var session = await client.LoginAsync(AppConfig.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS);
```

I am getting the below exception:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

with stack trace:

```
at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<PromptOAuthDialog>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at             System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<LoginAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<LoginAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProject.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.<OnFacebookLoginCommandReceived>d__e.MoveNext()
```

Can some one tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Running the app in Emulator takes me to login page and it works fine. But in mobile Its giving the above exception. I guess its something to do with settings. Please help.

Comment: Have you followed the complete example in [this blog](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/)?

Comment: Hi @ShawnKendrot I saw the blog and I have few questions to ask.

1. I am using LoginAsync method to take me to login webview.I need update on this.
2. If I want to try LoginWithApp then is it mandatory to register the App in dev center? Cant I just continue with the random ID generated by VS?
3. If I use LoginWithApp and if the mobile is not installed with facebook then what will happen ? Atleast LoginAsync will always take  to webview right ?

Comment: Is there a way to handle the LoginWithApp if there is no facebook app installed? So that I can then call LoginAsync as a fall back mechanism.

Comment: Honestly I do not know the answers to those questions. I can guess if they want to log in with facebook, they probably have the app installed

Answer (score 1):

I also face this issue so many times and found that this Error comes up due to Phone Incorrect Date Time   and once i correct the DateTime of my phone this issue get fixed, try once